# binding diferrent set of items in a list

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a list item with a datatemplate that has a several components all inside a stackpanel. Now i want to split size of the rows of the list evenly among the number of items in the list (depending on the number of rows) so if there are only 2 items in the list, the height of each of 2 the listitems will be (800/2), if 3 (800/3) e.t.c. (there's are limit at which the row size will remain constant)

My problem is how to do i bind this calculated height to the container (stackpanel) of the listitem? since i have set the listitems itemsource property and the 'container' is inside the list?

Comment: if u post ur code it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The way I would tackle this would be to create a `ValueConverter` that looks at the number of items in your `List<T>` and does the math to calculate how tall the individual `StackPanel` elements should be. It would then return this value as an `int`.

To put the pieces together, in your XAML you would bind your `StackPanel.Height` property to the `Count` property on your `List<T>`, specifying your `ValueConverter` as the property's converter.

The `DataContext` might get a little tricky when you try to access the `Count` property, since the `StackPanel` will have its `DataContext` set to the individual list item. But you can probably work around that by adding a `Count` property to each item in your list.

Here's a good post](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/) about `ValueConverter`. It covers converting a `bool` to a `Visibility` property, but the concepts are the same.